# Conflicting return types

Tags: c, declaration

I am doing a recursive program and I am getting an error about conflicting types:

```
void* buddyMalloc(int req_size)
{ 
     // Do something here
     return buddy_findout(original_index,req_size); // This is the recursive call
}

void *buddy_findout(int current_index,int req_size)
{
    char *selected = NULL;

    if(front!=NULL)
    {
        if(current_index==original_index)
        {
            // Do something here
            return selected;
        }
        else
        {
            // Do Something here
            return buddy_findout(current_index+1,req_size);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return buddy_findout(current_index-1,req_size);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
buddy.c: At top level:
buddy.c:76: error: conflicting types for ‘buddy_findout’
buddy.c:72: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘buddy_findout’ was here
```

Please note the file buddy.c in which I am defining this does not contain main and is linked with several other .c files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a function prior to its proper definition without a prototype. `buddy_malloc()` is using `buddy_findout()` before it is prototyped or defined, which the compiler will treat as a definition.

Prototype `buddy_findout()` prior to defining `buddy_Malloc()`, or define `buddy_findout()` prior to defining `buddy_Malloc()`.

I suggest prototypes, i.e:

```
void *buddy_Malloc(int);
void *buddy_findout(int, int);
```

... Just under your last `#include`

This avoids any confusion on the order that you define things. Also, consider using `size_t` (the largest unsigned int type available on the architecture) instead of signed integers when specifying sizes.

Here is your code (corrected) using both methods. Method 1 - using prototypes:

```
void *buddy_Malloc(int);
void *buddy_findout(int, int);

void* buddyMalloc(int req_size)
{ 
          //Do something here//
         return buddy_findout(original_index,req_size); //This is the recursive fn I call//
}

void *buddy_findout(int current_index,int req_size)
{
     char *selected = NULL;

     if(front!=NULL)
      {
            if(current_index==original_index)
            {
                    //Do something here//
                     return selected ; // 
             }
             else
             {
                 //Do Something here//
                 return buddy_findout(current_index+1,req_size);
              }
        }
       else
        {
                  return buddy_findout(current_index-1,req_size);
         }
}
```

And method 2, just re-ordering:

```
void *buddy_findout(int current_index,int req_size)
{
     char *selected = NULL;

     if(front!=NULL)
      {
            if(current_index==original_index)
            {
                    //Do something here//
                     return selected ; // 
             }
             else
             {
                 //Do Something here//
                 return buddy_findout(current_index+1,req_size);
              }
        }
       else
        {
                  return buddy_findout(current_index-1,req_size);
         }
}

void* buddyMalloc(int req_size)
{ 
          //Do something here//
         return buddy_findout(original_index,req_size); //This is the recursive fn I call//
}
```

In some circles it is sort of considered an *art* to not need prototypes for static functions, it kind of demonstrates the program was planned out in someone's head before code was written. I don't have much to say about that either way, other than recommending prototypes even for static functions to those who are still learning the nuts and bolts of C.

If `buddy_*` is going to be exposed for other modules to use, you really need prototypes. Its hard to tell if you intend these to be static or not.

**Edit:**

If you are putting the prototypes in an external header file, you need to use *include guards* to ensure that each module includes them only once (and doesn't re-define them to be the exact same thing).

Here is a sample `buddy.h`:

```
#ifndef BUDDY_H
#define BUDDY_H

void *buddy_Malloc(int);
void *buddy_findout(int, int);

#endif /* BUDDY_H */
```

The preprocessor will then keep your modules from throwing that error.

Comment: AS per your suggestion, I prototyped it in a file called buddy.h
But I am still getting errors like:

buddy.c: At top level:
buddy.c:76: error: conflicting types for ‘buddy_findout’
buddy.c:72: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘buddy_findout’ was here

Please note that, the function buddy.c in which I am defining this does not contain main and is linked with several other .c files

Comment: Adi, you've got a circular reference somewhere. Did you put include guards in the header? I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Adi, great, don't forget to select this answer if it fixed your problem.

Comment: @Tim, Thanks for the detailed explanation. Well I come in the category of learning nuts and bolts of C :)
--How do I select an answer ? Being a newbie, i dont knwo it..

I am now getting a stack overflow problem in the above recursive code.
Here is the message i got

*** glibc detected *** ./473_mem: free(): invalid pointer: 0x00c274c0 ***

473_mem was the executable file

Comment: @Adi - You probably want to open another question for that, since its not related to this one.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this has to be with missing prototypes.

Add the function prototype of

```
void *buddy_findout(int current_index,int req_size);
```

before the function `buddyMalloc`

Answer (score 0):

`buddy_findout` is declared to return a pointer to void, but in one place you're attempting to return `selected`, which is a pointer to char. As others have already pointed out, you also need a prototype for `buddy_findout`:

```
void *buddy_findout(int, int);

void *buddy_malloc(int req_size) { 
    return buddy_findout(original_index,req_size);
}

void *buddy_findout(int current_index, int req_size) {
// ...
    if (current_index == original_index)
        return (void *)selected;
// ...
}
```

Comment: Because char pointers are implicitly converted to void pointers, that is not a problem.  Casting to a void pointer is when returning is just superfluous.